How to make these cut lines?
How would be your approach to make those cut lines in the 3d model, you can see the sketch reference below to know what kind of cut lines would I like to do.

You can also see the method I was using which is using the boolean method.


But I also saw many different videos in youtube about how to do this, I just want to know the easiest way to do it and get a clean geometry if possible.
Because as you see I am using multiple meshes to make the booleans, by doing this sometimes the depth is not the same one (image 4)


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
